# How to get the text_field to work as html text input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The Desired Working state, was to know how to make an text_field with the correct params that will work with the gem, and this has been proven.

The issue is that emoji_picker gem did not work well with input field.

And a code example is provided down below:

This is my old input. It works to submit and the message gets sent:

```
  <div class="input-box">
    <input type="text" class="input-box_text" id="message_input"/>
  </div>
```

But then I wanted to use a emoji_picker in the input but still have it submit with the enter key:

```
class="emoji-picker-container">
  <%= text_field nil, class: 'input-box_text', data: { emojiable: true }, id: 'message_input' %>
</p>
```

The new input will not submit. I know the issue is with the id/class and the nil statement.

Comment: can you post your error trace?

Comment: Hello edmund, sorry to say it does not return an error the page loads as it should and no error in browser console.

Comment: I mean when you submit. You have the first argument as `nil`, and I think that's where the issue is. You're supposed to put the name of object as the first argument.

Comment: @the Tin Man I have now added a more descriptive desired working state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field

You need to specify the model name, and attribute name. From the doc, this is what you should do.

```
text_field(:post, :title, size: 20)
# => <input type="text" id="post_title" name="post[title]" size="20" value="#{@post.title}" />
```

What's important is not the `id`, but the `name` attribute. E.g., if you have `description` in your `Message` model, you should have something like this.

```
<%= text_field :message, :description, class: 'input-box_text', data: { emojiable: true }, id: 'message_input' %>
```

Then Rails will parse your form into a params like this:

```
{
  message: {
    description: '...'
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this: `params[:message][:description]`

***Here are some additional docs to help you understand how that works.***

- Rails uses `URI:: decode_www_form` to decode your HTML form. Refer to [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/URI/decode_www_form/class)
- Here's a [rebuilt simplified version](https://github.com/EdmundLeex/rails-lite/blob/master/lib/params.rb#L44) of how the Rails params works.
- And here's a reference of the html form encoding standard.

  https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data

Comment: Thanks will look into those articles, however as mentioned above it seems to add it self fine but the gem turns it into a text area so that is why the enter stops working and this in it self is the part i want to solve i know how to force it to match with jquery but i was hoping to somehow have it done without is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
<input class="input-box_text" data-emojiable="true" id="message_input" name="message[input]" type="text">
```

Comment: Thank you, it adds in everything but it looks like the emojiable turns the input into a text area that does not respond to send/submit with enter.

Comment: This sounds really weird. How do you handle the parameters in your controller?

Comment: i forgot to mention that this part is for actioncable i have built a chat so when you hit enter with those parameters it will send the message to the chat but for some reason the emoji_picker is making it into an text area and not sending the message. as now when you hit enter it will just make a new line. what i'm using for the emoji is https://github.com/ID25/rails_emoji_picker